# How to solve smtplib.SMTPDataError: (554, b'5.5.1 Error: no valid recipients') in python

Tags: python, smtplib, outlook-restapi

I have to functions send_output_mail which will call process_mail to send mail to the given  recipients with multiple attacthments.

Here is my code

```
import smtplib
from string import Template
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email import encoders
import os
import pandas as pd

server = '112.11.1.111'; port = 11
MY_ADDRESS = 'xyz@outlook.com'
from datetime import datetime



def process_email(**kwargs):  # accept variable number of keyworded arguments

    # get total email recipients
    rcpt = []
    for email in kwargs['emails']:
        for i in email:
            rcpt.append(i)

    # set up the SMTP server
    s = smtplib.SMTP(host=server, port=port)

    msg = MIMEMultipart()  # create a message
    # setup the parameters of the message, to cc emails
    msg['From'] = MY_ADDRESS
    msg['To'] = ','.join(kwargs['emails'][0])
    msg['Cc'] = ','.join(kwargs['emails'][1])
    msg['Subject'] = kwargs['subject']

    if 'attachments' in kwargs.keys():
        for attachment in kwargs['attachments']:
            fullpath_attactment = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"Output_file",attachment) #will give full path of the file 
            with open(fullpath_attactment) as fp:
                record = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
                record.set_payload(fp.read())
                encoders.encode_base64(record)
                record.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment',
                                  filename=os.path.basename(fullpath_attactment))
                msg.attach(record)

    s.sendmail(MY_ADDRESS, rcpt, msg.as_string())  **#Getting Error Here**
    s.quit()


def send_output_mail():
        emails = [["xyz@outlook.com", "hy@outlook.com"], ["xxx@outlook.com","yy@outlook.com"]]
        subject = "Reports"

        process_email(emails=emails, subject=subject, attachments= ["xx.csv","yy.csv"])
```

**Problem**
As i Debugged i am getting smtplib.SMTPDataError: (554, b'5.5.1 Error: no valid recipients') while  executing line

```
 s.sendmail(MY_ADDRESS, rcpt, msg.as_string())
```

I have crosschecked and the mailid that i have written and it was also correct, still getting this error.

Comment: Recheck the value of `rcpt`. The message says the server thinks it is not valid. And remember,  on this point the server is correct.

Comment: Bro, please check your smtp server details. It might be the case that the server where you're running the code doesn't have access to stmp server; meaning smtp doesn't know if that rcpt is valid or not.